# Created function with jquery and want use onclick but thats dont work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I have a form and want to add onClick function. `onclick()` function opens panel two!

When you click on grin line on right thats opens panel two I cut same function and put in another function which I gave onclick but it doesn't work.

This is my code I tried.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var panelOne = $(".form-panel.two").height(),
    panelTwo = $(".form-panel.two")[0].scrollHeight;

  $(".form-panel.two")
    .not(".form-panel.two.active")
    .on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $(".form-toggle").addClass("visible");
      $(".form-panel.one").addClass("hidden");
      $(".form-panel.two").addClass("active");
      $(".form").animate(
        {
          height: panelTwo,
        },
        200
      );
    });

  $(".form-toggle").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("visible");
    $(".form-panel.one").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".form-panel.two").removeClass("active");
    $(".form").animate(
      {
        height: panelOne,
      },
      200
    );
  });
});

function login() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var panelOne = $(".form-panel.two").height(),
      panelTwo = $(".form-panel.two")[0].scrollHeight;

    $(".form-panel.two")
      .not(".form-panel.two.active")
      .on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(".form-toggle").addClass("visible");
        $(".form-panel.one").addClass("hidden");
        $(".form-panel.two").addClass("active");
        $(".form").animate(
          {
            height: panelTwo,
          },
          200
        );
      });
  });
}
```

```css
.overlay,
.form-panel.one:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.form {
  z-index: 15;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 110px auto 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.form-toggle {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: translate(0, -25%) scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.form-toggle:before,
.form-toggle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #2eca6a;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.form-toggle:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.form-toggle:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.form-toggle.visible {
  transform: translate(0, -25%) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.form-group:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
.form-group label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
.two .form-group label {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.form-group input {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: inherit;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.form-group input:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.two .form-group input {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.two .form-group input:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.form-group button {
  outline: none;
  background: #2eca6a;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.two .form-group button {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #2eca6a;
}
.form-group .form-remember {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-transform: none;
}
.form-group .form-remember input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.form-group .form-recovery {
  color: #2eca6a;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form-panel {
  padding: 60px calc(5% + 60px) 60px 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-panel.one:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.form-panel.one.hidden:before {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.form-panel.two {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 95%;
  background: #2eca6a;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 60px calc(10% + 60px) 60px 60px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form-panel.two:before,
.form-panel.two:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 1.5%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 30px;
  width: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.form-panel.two:after {
  left: 3%;
}
.form-panel.two:hover {
  left: 93%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.form-panel.two:hover:before,
.form-panel.two:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.form-panel.two.active {
  left: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: default;
}
.form-panel.two.active:before,
.form-panel.two.active:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.form-header {
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}
.form-header h1 {
  padding: 4px 0;
  color: #2eca6a;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.two .form-header h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 40;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Form-->
    <div class="form">
        <div class="form-toggle"></div>
        <div class="form-panel one">
            <div class="form-header">
                <h1>Մուտք</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Անուն</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Գաղտնաբառ</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-remember">
                            <button onclick="login()">Գրանցվել</button>
                        </label>
                        <a class="form-recovery" href="#">Մոռացե՞լ ես գաղտնաբառը</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit">Մտնել</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-panel two">
            <div class="form-header">
                <h1>Գրանցվել</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Անուն</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Գաղտնաբառ</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cpassword">Հաստատել գաղտնաբառը</label>
                        <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Էլ․ հասցե</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit">Գրանցվել</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: _"This is my whole code"_ - SO is not a free code debugging service -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_ + _""It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_